# Exporting Access DB to SQL Server: unexpected EOF?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

How do I correctly export a table from an old Access `.mdb` to SQL Server 2012?

In Access I do: right click on table, export as text file and use comma or tab separator.
My line endings are `CRLF` as seen from Notepad++

Then when I try to import into my RDS SQL Server with

```
bcp dbname.dbo.tablename in C:\AllModels.txt -n 
    -S servername -U username -P password -b 10000
```

I am getting:

> Starting copy...
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

*help help*

Comment: Use tab and try `-c` instead of `-n`

Comment: Now I'm getting a bunch of `SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation`

69 rows got copied out of 681

Comment: Compare the column size in your destination table(s) with the length of the data being imported - there is a mismatch somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use tab delimited files unless you want to use `-t` to specify a different delimiter (such as a comma). By default it will accept the tab.

Next, unless you're exporting data with the `-n` flag, use `-c` to import the data.

Finally, based on your comments, it looks like there is a mis-match between the size of your table columns and the actual width of the data. That's why you're getting notified the data is being truncated. Match those two up and you'll be all set.

You can check out the [MSDN page on bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) for more information on flags, etc.